# Force new parse installation

Tags: android, parse-platform

as I previously asked in this question: [Clear parse installation cache on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433296/clear-parse-installation-cache-on-android)

I would like to delete/clear the parse installation on my android phone when a user logs out of the app. I can delete the parse installation via a script from the web, then I have to clear it from the ram/disk on the phone.

My question is, how can I force the parse library to trigger creating a new parse installation after I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to successfully delete the 'local' ParseInstallation cache using the **android parse sdk 1.13.1**

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
Class clazz = installation.getClass();
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
Method method1 = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getCurrentInstallationController");
method1.setAccessible(true);
Object result = method1.invoke(installation);

Method method2 = result.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clearFromDisk");
method2.setAccessible(true);
String result2=(String) method2.invoke(result);

Method method3 = result.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clearFromMemory");
method3.setAccessible(true);
String result3=(String) method3.invoke(result);
```

Everytime my app starts I check if the installation can be saved, if it can't I just recreate another installation.

This way, it's safe to delete the installation from parse-server depending on your use case, My ParseInstallation only holds a reference to my User object so I can query and send Push notifications.

```
final ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        installation.saveInBackground()
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<Void>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Void> then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                        if (task.isFaulted()) {
                            try {
                                ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                                Class clazz = installation.getClass();
                                Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
                                Method method1 = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getCurrentInstallationController");
                                method1.setAccessible(true);
                                Object result = method1.invoke(installation);

                                Method method2 = result.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clearFromDisk");
                                method2.setAccessible(true);
                                String result2=(String) method2.invoke(result);

                                Method method3 = result.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clearFromMemory");
                                method3.setAccessible(true);
                                String result3=(String) method3.invoke(result);

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                })
```

Hope this makes a little sense...

Comment: Which is not an accurate representation of the app state. An installation exists on the device as long as the app is not uninstalled. If you delete the installation from the server, then the server knows less than the client, which may not be what you want conceptually.